# How to convert ImageIO.write(input, file, cos) to use in Android

Tags: android

Im a getting errors from some code developed in Java that want to use in Android.

```
ImageIO.write(input, file, cos)
```

These are my errors for the following code in android, the code works in Java:
BufferedImage cannot be resolved to a type
ImageIO cannot be resolved

```
 public void decryptFile(String key, String typeFile) throws InvalidKeyException, 
                                                          NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                                                       InvalidKeySpecException, 
                                                            NoSuchPaddingException, 
                                                                       IOException
   {

       DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
       SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
       SecretKey desKey = skf.generateSecret(dks);
       Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding for SunJCE

       pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);    


        // Decrypt the ciphertext and then print it out.     
        FileInputStream output = null;

        File encryptedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/Et1.jpg");   
        File decryptedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/Dt1.jpg");


        try 
        {

        output = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(output, pbeCipher);
    BufferedImage input = null;

    try 
    {
        input = ImageIO.read(cis);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try 
    {
        out = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        ImageIO.write(input,typeFile, out);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try 
    {
        cis.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had similar problems with

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
```

You need to find the corresponding import (probably ImageIO)
and find a replacement
for me it was

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
```

if thats not the case then post your errors.
Also take in mind it wasnt just a matter of switching the import, i had to port the code to the new library.